# can we get all methods from c# console application

Tags: c#, console

I want to get all Methods in  c# files in console application. how can we get all methods?. how can be used console this application in  to get all methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the public methods of a type using reflection. If your file represents a class, then typeof(yourclassname).GetMethods() will return all the public methods.

Comment: its working  but if its class is store in another drive as file .then how we can all get methods